# Agda, Boolean Proposition

Tags: haskell, agda

A foreword note that this is for an assignment. A question has already been asked about for the first question. So we have the data type:

```
data BoolProp : ??? where
  ptrue  : BoolProp true
  pfalse : BoolProp false
  pand   : (P Q : Bool) -> (BoolProp P) -> (BoolProp Q) -> BoolProp (P ??? Q)
  por    : (P Q : Bool) -> (BoolProp P) -> (BoolProp Q) -> BoolProp (P ??? Q)
  pnot   : (P : Bool) -> BoolProp (not P)
```

Now we're being asked to write the proposition

```
eval (PAnd (POr PTrue PFalse) PFalse)
```

which should return `BoolProp` `false`

I'm Just getting confused on how to do this. `Ptrue` returns `BoolProp true` however with the data type `por` takes in two `Bool`'s not `BoolProp`'s. Maybe the data type is wrong. Any heads up would be great

I should add that the eval code is a snippet from the haskell code

note: editted it to not give everything away

Comment: lol kinda pushing arent we its due at 12

Comment: better late than never, but still you're reply isn't really too helpful. and i did start it yesterday morning

Comment: haha yea it isnt. I just started it as well, obviously i was trying to google the answer as well and ended up here.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah lets hope someone can give an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your code is not compiling is because the bracketing in your first section is incorrect. 
For example, for pand it should be like
  pand : ∀ { P Q : Bool } → BoolProp P → BoolProp Q → BoolProp (P ∧ Q )

Change that and the second part should compile.
I had exactly the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

well i dunno if it right or not and this is just for the first part
if your taking about the eval on the last question, i dunno.

But for the first part since the type signature is

```
prop : BoolProp false
```

I just made prop equal to the eval statement.
Since the eval statement should equal to BoolProp.

so

```
prop = (pand (por ptrue pfalse) pfalse)
```

maybe its wrong, i dunno
but it C-c C-l
and C-c C-n

and I am happy.

Comment: are you sure? because when i didit i get the error (BoolType true) !=< Bool of type Set when checking that the expression ptrue has type Bool. Did you use the code i put up exactly or altered it a bit?